# Oracle BI reports importing template

Tags: java, oracle, pdf, report, business-intelligence

I am trying to import a report in Oracle BI publisher from a PDF generated by other software, Is it possible I can write java code if that can help to get it imported in BI.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/). It lets you work with pdf files. Use the API to read the file and then import the relevant data using an import process (JDBC, Spring JDBC template, etc)